# Edit letter-spacing from Sublime's sidebar font?

Tags: sublimetext3

As many of you might know, if you want to style your Sublime text's sidebar without installing any theme, you can make a file just like this one:

https://gist.github.com/MrDrews/5434948

Which contains some ccs-like code that allows you to edit some visual properties on Sublime.

However, I've searched for more classes and properties for this ccs-like code that have let me edit other things.

I can't seem to find any way to edit the letter-spacing on the Sidebar though.

I would appreciate if someone could explain me more about this way of editing Sublime text's appearance. And everything that you can edit with it.

And specially if it is possible to edit the letter-spacing on the sidebar.
Thanks (:

Comment: There is no option in `.sublime-theme` files to adjust the kerning, or space between letters. You'll just need to pick a different font if you don't like the one you have by using the `font.face` property as described below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can affect the sidebar font appearance by editing the `font.face` and `font.size` properties of the `sidebar_label` class.

```
{
    "class": "sidebar_label",
    "color": [116, 140, 161],
    "font.size": 11.0,
    "font.face": "Consolas"
},
```

---

There may be more subproperties of `font`; but you will likely have to find them by exploring existing themes, as official `sublime-theme` documentation is nonexistent for the time being.

I recommend using the following themes as reference when researching theme related issues:

- [**SpaceGray**](https://github.com/kkga/spacegray/blob/master/Spacegray.sublime-theme)
- [**Soda**](https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme/blob/master/Soda%20Dark%203.sublime-theme)
- [**Otto**](https://github.com/oivva/otto/blob/master/Otto%20Monokai.sublime-theme)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
As I thought there is no official documentation for this property. 
I'd like to know how to explore a theme if you can help me out with that too.

Comment: @Lynnks : Just check out [**Themes @ PackageControl**](https://packagecontrol.io/browse/labels/theme) and browse through the `.sublime-theme` files on their GitHub pages. You can just read through them to gain a general understanding of what classes & properties are available, or you can try to `find` a specific keyword within the file.  I linked to a few themes that are pretty well documented in my answer.